# Is it possible to align several divs to the bottom of a parent div, but not use absolute position?

Tags: css

I have a div that has a bunch of child divs.  I would like the last N child divs to stack on top of one another at the bottom.  So, the idea would be that the last one would be all the way at the bottom, and the one before would be just above it, etc.

I realize that I can position them absolutely, but then I have to use javascript to manually move them off from the bottom (setting the bottom property to their height * their reverse order). I was hoping there's a straight CSS way to accomplish this task, but I'm not seeing it.

All help welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the child divs in another div that is positioned absolutely to the bottom, and then they should stack normally within that div.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/34rRB/

Comment: so simple... I should have thought of it... very nice, thanks.

Comment: Works for sure. but I'm in the same boat - and I'm worried that depending on the content, that this wont scale well. Take this fiddle and make the window really small. http://jsfiddle.net/34rRB/3/ The boxes eventually overlap. This wouldn't be such a problem in most cases, but say your client changes an h2, in the CMS backend, from "contact us" to "get in touch with one of our representatives." that h2 is going to do things you couldn't account for after it gets larger, Especially with any fixed sized divs.

Comment: Best answer so far. Up vote. But, I still think there is some way to drop a div to the baseline and keep it in the page flow... but maybe I'll have to be happy with CSS handling 98 percent of things perfectly.

Comment: Generally I just have a minimum height/width that I aim to support (usually something like 320x480), and just set a min-width to some wrapper parent to ensure that those minimums are always met. If you're worried about your design breaking at small sizes though, you should consider looking into CSS media queries, that let you dynamically change styles based on the current window size.